# How to redirect wlan0 to eth0?

Tags: linux

I have a router that is connected via Ethernet to my raspberry pi and then my raspberry pi is connected to the internet via WiFi!

How can I forward my WiFi signal through my Ethernet to my router and then from my router to my devices?

I have already tried iptables and udchpd but I couldn't configure the router to get the forwarded  traffic from the pi! Please help.

Many thanks,
Isaac.

Comment: Please include information about your network topology and the IP layout of your network.

Comment: Just a standard network which has my pi attached which I want to forward through eth0 to my other router

Answer (score 0):

You have something like this?

Internet_Server ------------- Raspberry_Pi --------- Router----dev(n)

where dev(n) is standing in for all the devices you have off the different ports in your router. But does everything in your network have a static address or is it expecting a dynamic address from the internet server? And how are you getting traffic across the Raspberry Pi?

If everything already has an IP address, you could use IP forwarding to get across the Rasberry Pi. This won't work if you are using DHCP - you can't use IP forwarding for something that doesn't have an IP address. As I understand it, you cannot use routing with DHCP either. With either static or dynamic addresses, [you could use a bridge](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bridge#Does_DHCP_work_over.2Fthrough_a_bridge.3F), although, at least at one point, some wireless cards couldn't be used in a bridge. If it were me, I would try setting up a bridge on the Raspberry Pi and hope that my wireless card would allow it. If you are using iptables, you will need to be sure forwarding is allowed for the bridge, as in [this example I found](http://bwachter.lart.info/linux/bridges.html).

Comment: Thanks but can you give me an example of what I would do step by step?

Comment: set up iptables but can't seem to set up dhcp server. And how would i set up router?

Comment: You are definitely using dynamic addresses? I would think that the internet server on your wireless connection would be your dhcp server and the bridge and router would be dhcp clients. But you are getting to the point were I don't feel adequate to give you advice.You might want to add some more information to your original post, as Frank Thomas suggested, and see if someone more network savvy comes along. You will want to tell people what your wireless is connecting to (a router off a cable modem? a public access point?), and what your router looks like (software, hardware), etc.

Comment: I don't know. I am just trying to make a wireless network that gets its internet access from another wireless network by forwarding ports using a raspberry pi